About filtering the data of different length using R studio
I have dataset of 1000 rows and 800 columns. I want to filter the non-zero values from each column and prepare a new dataset containing only non-zero values in each columns. Problem is that every column has different length and position of non-zero values. That is the hindrance to get the values by simply applying the filter function. My input dataset look like the given table below.



point1
point2
point3




-0.2
0
0


0
0.8
0


0
0
2.8


-0.5
0
0


0
0
0


0
0
-0.5


0
1.8
0


-0.25
0
0


0
0
-0.63


0.47
0
0


0
2.8
0


0
0
-0.58


0
0
-0.58



And, my desired output is:



point1
point2
point3




-0.2
0.8
2.8


-0.5
1.8
2.8


-0.25
2.8
-0.63


0.47

-0.58




-0.58



I am using R with RStudio to handle this problem:
 df1<- read.csv("D:/New folder/AnomalyY.csv")
 df1 <- setDT(df1)
 filfun <- function(data){
  rows <- apply(data, 1, function(x) all(x !=0))
  filtered_data <- data[rows,] 
   return(filtered_data)}

  filtered_data <- filfun(df1)
  print(filtered_data)

But, this script work only with one column not with multiple columns at once...
If there is any other way to accomplish this task, any approach or any other programming language, kindly guide me.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images. Ultimately the question because what type of object do you want to store the data in, because data.frames and data.tables require "rectangular" data where each row has the same number of columns and you seem to want something else.

Thank you for your response. I want to attach reproducible example input and desired output.. But, I couldn't figure out how to attach it. Can you please share with me your email address? I will send you my excel etc.. Thank you for your help.

Welcome to SO. To share a sample of your data, you have different options: 1) You can build a data.frame (look at my answer for an example), 2) You can use dput(head(df1)) and paste the result in your question, others can copy that in a script to get the data, 3) You can use the constructive package, which is a friendlier version of dput.

If you need a data.frame (or data.table), all columns must have same length. So, you must replace 0 with NA values. Then all operations (sum, mean, ...) will operate as if they don't exist (as long as you set na.rm = TRUE). Then, you can also export to CSV and set NA to empty (write.csv(df2, "df2.csv", na = "").
library(data.table)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
~ point1,   ~ point2, ~ point3,
-0.2,   0,  0,
0,  0.8,    0,
0,  0,  2.8,
-0.5,   0,  0,
0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  -0.5,
0,  1.8,    0,
-0.25,  0,  0,
0,  0,  -0.63,
0.47,   0,  0,
0,  2.8,    0,
0,  0,  -0.58,
0,  0,  -0.58,
)

df1 <- setDT(df1)

df1_mat <- df1 |> 
  as.matrix()

# Return a data.table (it must be rectangular)
df1_mat[df1_mat == 0] <- NA

df2 <- df1_mat |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  setDT()

df2
#>     point1 point2 point3
#>  1:  -0.20     NA     NA
#>  2:     NA    0.8     NA
#>  3:     NA     NA   2.80
#>  4:  -0.50     NA     NA
#>  5:     NA     NA     NA
#>  6:     NA     NA  -0.50
#>  7:     NA    1.8     NA
#>  8:  -0.25     NA     NA
#>  9:     NA     NA  -0.63
#> 10:   0.47     NA     NA
#> 11:     NA    2.8     NA
#> 12:     NA     NA  -0.58
#> 13:     NA     NA  -0.58

If you do need different lengths in the result, you can use lapply but it returns a list of vectors:

lapply(df1, \(x) x[x != 0])
#> $point1
#> [1] -0.20 -0.50 -0.25  0.47
#> 
#> $point2
#> [1] 0.8 1.8 2.8
#> 
#> $point3
#> [1]  2.80 -0.50 -0.63 -0.58 -0.58

But this can't be converted back to a data.frame:
lapply(df1, \(x) x[x != 0]) |> as.data.frame()
#> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3, 5

Created on 2024-04-19 with reprex v2.0.2

Thank you Josep Pueyo for your help and sending me detailed solution. I tried it and it worked well. Thanks again.

If that worked, can you please mark the answer as correct so others can benefit too?

Sure, I have marked it. Thank you very much
